# Trying to change array of arrays into array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Trying to convert an array of arrays into an array.
for example: 
I would like to convert `[["1"],["2"],["3"]]` to `[1,2,3]`

I tried a number of solutions, but none of the solutions seem to work on the latest working swift (Swift 4).

```
 var lat = [] as [[String]]
    for i in 0..<holder.count {
        if i % 4 == 0 {
            lat.append(holder[i] as! [String])
        }
        if ((i+1) % 4) == 0 {
            type.append(holder[i])
        }
        if (i % 4) == 1 {
            long.append(holder[i])
        }
        if (i % 4) == 2 {
            speed.append(holder[i])
        }
    }


    let reducedLat = lat.joined().compactMap(Int.init)
    print(lat)
    print(reducedLat)
```

This code produces nothing, i would like to know why xcode doesnt recognise the values in lat? to convert it to the datatype i would like. 
Thanks!

When i try to cast to Int straightaway it throws an error too...

```
var lat = [] as [[Int]]
    //let reducedLat = lat.joined().compactMap(Int.init)
    //print(reducedLat)

    for i in 0..<holder.count {
        if i % 4 == 0 {
            lat.append(holder[i] as! [Int])
        }
        if ((i+1) % 4) == 0 {
            type.append(holder[i])
        }
        if (i % 4) == 1 {
            long.append(holder[i])
        }
        if (i % 4) == 2 {
            speed.append(holder[i])
        }

    }



    print(lat)
```

The error on the log - 'Could not cast value of type 'Swift.String' (0x1051c49f8) to 'Swift.Int''

Comment: *"I tried a number of solutions"* – what about showing one or two attempts, so that we can point out the problem?

Comment: Do you also want to convert the content as in your example, string to int, or is that a typo?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @JoakimDanielson, it wasn't a typo i wanted to know how to do that. Martin R- I will learn from this mistake and will post my solutions in the future. Currently on a question ban, so was wondering how i can improve this question(talking to the community as a whole)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Flatten the array with `flatMap`
- `map` the `String` array to `Int`

  ```
  let array = [["1"],["2"],["3"]]
  let flattenedArray = array.flatMap{$0}.map(Int.init)
  ```

or

- Flatten the array with `joined`
- `compactMap` the `String` array to `Int`

  ```
  let array = [["1"],["2"],["3"]]
  let flattenedArray = array.joined().compactMap(Int.init)
  ```

Comment: `array.joined().map(Int.init)` might be more intuitive, or `array.joined().compactMap(Int.init)` to get rid of the optionals.

Comment: var test = [["1"],["2"],["3"],["4"],["5"]] as [Any]
        let reducedLat = test.flatMap{$0}.map(Int.init)
        let reducedLat1 = test.joined().compactMap(Int.init)
        
        print(reducedLat)
        print(reducedLat1)


Both approaches proved unsuccessful...

The first approach produces an array of zeros.
The second approach doesnt compute, due to joined throwing error - 'Ambiguous reference to member 'joined()''

Comment: @xRumbleLorex Don't cast a distinct type (`[[String]]`) which the compiler can infer to a quite unspecified one (`[Any]`).

Comment: Thanks with that tidbit it seemed to produce the desired result. Thanks, sorry to ask such a petty question, im quite new to this only have built one app previously.
Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, it seemed to have worked for the test but when I try to apply this technique it seems to produce nothing. 
This is the data im trying to convert...
[["51.559106"], ["51.545983"], ["51.539874"], ....]

Comment: These strings represent floating point numbers, in this case replace `Int.init` with `Double.init`